# What happens if a user decides to change the time of the device?

Tags: android, timestamp

In my app I have a set of topics that I retrieve from a database, now each topic has a set of data including a (`timestamp`).

**timestamp: is the time when the topic was posted to the database.**

Now I only allow users to enter the topic if and only if the difference between the `timestamp` and the `currentTime` of the device is greater than 2 weeks.

**Problem:**

I noticed a problem where a user can change the time of the device and then enter the topic, and then he can change the time back.

What should I do to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this database on the device?

Comment: @TEK292 no the dtabase is on a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively from what has been said by Udit, you can avoid to use local device time and use as timestamp the time got from your server.

Comment: How is this better?

Comment: @data It is better because you are protecting your system from 'malicious' users. Servers should not assume that anything they get from a device is valid. As your bug demonstrates, users can lie and, if you aren't careful, get away with it.

Comment: It is user/device independent.. obviously you will refer to the server time even for the `currentTime` comparing it to the `timestamp`

Comment: Just a curious question: How companies like Netflix know that it has been a month since you last paid?

Comment: checking the timestamp they have on their db based for sure on a reliable server timestamp

Comment: But does the timestamp on server same as the current time for each device in each country?

Comment: No the timestamp will not be "same as current time" for all because of timezones.. that is because even for currentTime you will refer always to server time.. in this way that time will be "unique" and same for each device in each country

Comment: In any case this is the solution commonly used when you have distributed applications

Comment: ahh so if each device requested a current time from the same server then all will be counting the same time?

Comment: Yes it's like everyone is watching the same clock :) everything will be correctly synchronized on the same clock

Answer (score 2):

To avoid those cases, we need to use another method. Android has a good utility class, SystemClock. SystemClock.elapsedRealTime() is the method you should use.

This returns elapsed time in milliseconds since the system was booted. This includes time spend in sleep such as CPU off, display dark, and etc.

You can can calculate the difference based on elapsed time which is not affected by change in the date/time by the user.

EDIT: For an absolute full proof solution, you have to rely on the server time as well.
For example, Whenever a boot/reset occurs, you will have to fetch the updated ttl (time to live) from the server and use that with elapsed time.

For example, initial ttl is 14 days but user resets the phone after 2 days.
You will need to get the updated ttl from the server which will now give 12 days.

Comment: Is this kind of time affected by phone reset, or factory reset?

Comment: So this means it is not efficient?

Comment: How is the time on the server same as time on the device?

Comment: Its not the same..server will not give you the time, but the number of miliseconds for which the content is valid from that point on. Depending on when you ask the server, you will get different value for ttl which is the remaining time the data is valid for